# How to change the ports in WSO2 APIM without changing the offset

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have a requirement to change the default port(9443) of wso2 apim being exposed.
This was kind of easily achieved using docker say with running and mapping with docker like:

```
docker run -it -p 2083:9443 -p 2092:8443 --name api-manager wso2/wso2am:2.6.0
```

This is because the server supports exposing 2083 but not 9443 to public. I would need something similar to be done when trying to run the binary with the following command

```
sh wso2server.sh
```

Cannot use the offset method  `<Offset>-7360</Offset>` . As this will change other corresponding ports as well say need 2092 to be instead of 8443.

Comment: The 9443 port is set in <API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml file. You can manually change the port parameter in 
        `<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />` configuration. 
You only can set the port offset during the server startup.

Comment: Hi @Menaka , I need to change 2 ports 9443(publisher and store) to 2083 and 8243(api endpoint port) to 2092

Comment: changing both simultaneously is the issue. with offset the other port also will be changing parallely as per the offset say, offset 10 will make 9453 and 8253

Comment: The Port 8243 is used by the synapse. To change this port, you can change the `port` parameter in `<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener">` of axis2.xml file. The current config is 8243, you can change it to 2083.